# How to structure the rules for private message between 2 users in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security

I'm building a messaging system where the user A can send a private message to another user B while they both users are allowed to write and read, except the user C is not allowed to write or read to this message because it's private between 2 users, I had no idea how to do this.

My current rules:

```
"private_messages":{
  "$message_id":{
     ".read": "root.child('authorized-users').hasChild(auth.uid)",
     ".write":"root.child('messages').hasChild(auth.uid)",
     "message_content": {0: 'Hello', ...}
   }
}


"authorized-users:"{
  "$message_id": {
    "user1": 'A',
    "user2": 'B'
 }
}
```

I was unable to understand how it's supposed to work it... any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This requires the use of **FCM**/*Firebase Cloud Messaging*, there is a **key-mapping** technique for every user. In this, when you want to send messages to everyone , you put all these keys in an array and send your message.

If you just want an exchange between two users, just use their keys. Firebase has a *'to'* section just like when sending an email to someone. In this, you put the key. Refer to **FirebaseAPI** for more details on the same.

---

**Edit 1 :**  A chat application Android : link [here](https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/firebase/real-time-android-chat-application-using-firebase-tutorial/).

**Edit 2:** Since you said Javascript, a [firebase tutorial for React Native](https://medium.com/react-native-development/build-a-chat-app-with-firebase-and-redux-part-1-8a2197fb0f88) should suffice.

Comment: That's not what I want, I did not mean SMS, just simple chat like layout from facebook messenger or whatsapp.

Comment: Added a tutorial link , it should be of use.

Comment: I'm using Web version as Javascript, it's kinda hard to understand how to port from android to web, since this tutorial doesn't show how to structure the rules for chat.

Comment: Oh okay, javascript, React Native link should be helpful for that . Link in edit:)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what I am looking because I was looking the rules are supposed to allow someone can read and write for 2 users to access the mutual chat in json format